# Get the last string of the path

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I tried lots of things but could not find any accurate answer, My question is how to find last string of a file path without extension.

```
For example my path is :
 ~/Document/UK_0004/OldStateNoc/THE_RAIN.txt
```

and I want result like this

```
Output: THE_RAIN
```

I tries this, But not get sufficient answer

```
DECLARE @st1 VARCHAR(max)
SET @st1 = '~/Document/UK_0004/OldStateNoc/THE_RAIN.txt'     

select right(@st1, charindex('/', reverse(@st1)) - 1)
```

this give me

```
THE_RAIN.txt
```

I also dont want extension of file also, Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your same method for '.' also. ANd it will work

```
DECLARE @st1 VARCHAR(max)
SET @st1 = '~/Document/UK_0004/OldStateNoc/THE_RAIN.txt'     
Declare @st2 varchar(max)
(select @st1 = right(@st1, charindex('/', reverse(@st1)) - 1))

select left(@st1, charindex('.', @st1)-1)
```